# http response status code request limit

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, http-status

I have List String "names" contains list of urls. (Around 500 000 URLs). 
I want to get HTTP status code for this list quickly.

```
Dim req As HttpWebRequest<br>
  Dim resp As HttpWebResponse<br>
     For Each elem As String In Names<br>
     req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(flag_http)<br>
  Try<br>
     resp = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)<br>
     Catch ex As WebException<br>
     resp = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse)<br>
     ' Here I add these response codes to ms access database (using     resp.StatusCode)<br>
   End Try
```

But code doesn't work after getting responses for several URLs(5-6 URLs).
So I added

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000000
```

But even then, gets stuck on around 50-55 URLs.

But this should be fast, because the list is huge and time consuming.

What are my options to get around that request limit?

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Remove the br's and simply indent it four spaces. You can do this by selecting it and clicking the code button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your title and removed the tag from it. I furthermore improved the formatting of your code. You might want to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a better idea of the features we have and what we expect from posts.

Comment: What are the exact http status errors you get? Are all those urls pointing to resources on the same site?

Comment: Hi Thank you for taking time to edit my question.
It doesn't give any error, just hangs up.
I googled it and came across this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838901/httpwebresonse-hangs-on-multiple-request
It can handle only 50 requests at one time.
Any suggestions are welcome.